# Determine if $f$ is differentiable, and computing $f '(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, solution-verification

I would like to know if I did this correctly:

Let $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x} & x \ne 0\\
0&x=0
\end{matrix}\right. , x_{0}=0$$

So $$f'(x)=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}-0}{x-0}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}=1$$

Is that correct?

I didn't use the part that $f(x)=0$ if $x=0$ so I think that I'm missing something here.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are you computing? It looks like you are computing $f'(0),$ and you have used the condition $f(0)=0$ in the second equality ($\lim\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim\frac{f(x)-0}{x-0}$).

Comment: I need to determine if $f$ is differentiable at $x_{0}$, in this case at $0$, and compute $f'(x_{0})$. You are right, I just feel that it was too "easy"...

Comment: Your computation looks valid to me, if that's your question.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the confirmation! :)

Comment: You clearly used the value of $f(x_0)=0$ in the limit